# Picking out elements not in an 1-D array?

Tags: arrays, awk

I have a 1-D array

`x1 = [1, 2, 3, …, 10]`

which is stored in the file `x1.dat` as one record (all on one line), separated by commas.  `x1.dat` reads

`1,2,3,4,5,..., 10`

And there are two arrays

`array1 = [1,3]`, and `array2= [4,7]`

(elements in `array1` and `array2` are some elements of the array `x1`).

I want to select all the element which is neither in array1 nor in array2. 
The desired output will read

`2,5,6,8,9,10`

I tried with awk:

`$awk 'BEGIN{array1 = (1,3); array2 = (4,7)} {for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ((!($i in a1)) && (!($i in a2))) {print $i }}'  x1.dat`

This does not work.  Could you please help me to correct it or give a better way to do this selection?

Comment: `array1 = (82,173,242,83,174,247)` is shell syntax. awk is not shell. When you say `I have a 1-D array x1 = [1, 2, 3, …, 1000] (stored in the file: x1.dat)` - what does that mean? Are you just saying you have the values `1, 2, 3, …, 1000` stored in file `x1.dat`? If so, in what format? 1 per line, all on one line, separated by spaces, separated by some other character, or what? Post a sample of `x1.dat` and post the output you want to get after you run your command on that file.

Comment: Sorry I should say the format is: all on one line,separated by commas. For example, it reads ``1,2,3,4,5,..., 1000``

Comment: OK then update your question to show that and add your desired output given that input otherwise we're all still guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the text format of your data file. I assume it is one element per line.

You have a couple of problems in your codes.

- variable assignment, you cannot assign an awk array like that.
- the `in` usage is checking the array (hashtable actually) keys, not values.

it would be easier if you put the array1 and 2 in file, or input string, not in codes, but I am keeping it there for showing how to solve the problem exactly as you described

better read version:

```
awk -v arr1="<yourArray1Str>" -v arr2="<yourArray2Str>" 
    'BEGIN{
        split(arr1,a,",");
        split(arr2,b,",");
        for(x in a)k[a[x]]=1;
        for(x in b)k[b[x]]=1}
    !k[$0]' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
1
2
3
4
5

kent$  awk -v arr1="2,4,3" -v arr2="1,3,4" 'BEGIN{split(arr1,a,",");split(arr2,b,",");for(x in a)k[a[x]]=1;for(x in b)k[b[x]]=1}!k[$0]' f                                   
5
```